# Builder setter error on jsp

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, tomcat, servlets

Having problem with setting property value on jsp when using builder setter (with default works fine). Сode below causing exception javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: No setter method in <set> for property "name"

```
private String name;

public Role setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
}


<jsp:useBean id="userRole" class="spring.model.Role" type="spring.model.Role"/>
            <c:set value="user" target="${userRole}" property="name"/>
```

Comment: it only works with setters/getters to follow the Java Bean spec. A non-void method doesn't follow that and as such will not work.

Comment: so, there is no way to make it work with builder setter?

Comment: you need a proper setter method

Comment: No. Next to that you mention that you are using Spring MVC, so I would argue that you shouldn't even be using `jsp:useBean` in the first place.

Comment: i'm just starting to learn Spring, can u please push me in right direction to what should i do